# sql alchemy connection termination on airflow initdb

Tags: python, macos, sqlalchemy, python-3.5, airflow

I am using `Airflow v1.9.0` with `Python 3.5.2`.
I have a running staging and production environment at which it's working fine.
I was also using it locally on my local Ubuntu machine where it was working fine.
Recently I switched to `MacOS 10.15.2` from my old `Ubuntu 18`.

### Problem

When I do `$airflow initdb` or `$airflow upgradedb`, I get this messy SQL Alchemy error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/userabc/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vmds/bin/airflow", line 27, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/Users/userabc/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vmds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 897, in initdb
    db_utils.initdb()
  File "/Users/userabc/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vmds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 103, in initdb
    upgradedb()
  File "/Users/userabc/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vmds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 320, in upgradedb
    command.upgrade(config, 'heads')
  File "/Users/userabc/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vmds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/alembic/command.py", line 174, in upgrade
    script.run_env()
  File "/Users/userabc/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vmds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/alembic/script/base.py", line 416, in run_env
    util.load_python_file(self.dir, 'env.py')
  File "/Users/userabc/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vmds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/alembic/util/pyfiles.py", line 93, in load_python_file
    module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
  File "/Users/userabc/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vmds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/alembic/util/compat.py", line 68, in load_module_py
    module_id, path).load_module(module_id)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 388, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 809, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 668, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 268, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 693, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/userabc/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vmds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/migrations/env.py", line 86, in <module>
    run_migrations_online()
  File "/Users/userabc/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vmds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/migrations/env.py", line 73, in run_migrations_online
    with connectable.connect() as connection:
  File "/Users/userabc/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vmds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2102, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/userabc/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vmds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 90, in __init__
    if connection is not None else engine.raw_connection()
  File "/Users/userabc/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vmds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2188, in raw_connection
    self.pool.unique_connection, _connection)
  File "/Users/userabc/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vmds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2162, in _wrap_pool_connect
    e, dialect, self)
  File "/Users/userabc/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vmds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1476, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    exc_info
  File "/Users/userabc/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vmds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 265, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/Users/userabc/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vmds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 248, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/userabc/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vmds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2158, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "/Users/userabc/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vmds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 342, in unique_connection
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/Users/userabc/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vmds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 788, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/Users/userabc/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vmds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 529, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/Users/userabc/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vmds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 1193, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "/Users/userabc/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vmds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 66, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "/Users/userabc/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vmds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 249, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/userabc/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vmds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 1190, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/Users/userabc/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vmds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 347, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/Users/userabc/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vmds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 474, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "/Users/userabc/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vmds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 671, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/Users/userabc/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vmds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 106, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/Users/userabc/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vmds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 412, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/Users/userabc/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/vmds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
 (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

### Configuration

When I do

```
$ grep sql_alchemy_conn $AIRFLOW_HOME/airflow.cfg
```

I can see this output on my terminal

```
sql_alchemy_conn=postgresql://airflow-user:airflow-pwd@localhost/airflow-db
```

I can even connect to this database given the credentials mentioned in connection string using `DataGrip`.

### Checked

I did

```
$brew services list | grep postgres
```

and I can see that the service is running fine

```
postgresql started saadali /Users/userabc/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

Just to double check, even though it was running that's why I was able to connect through `Datagrip`.
What am I doing wrong? Is there anything different on `MacOS`?

> **Note**: 2/3 days ago I set airflow up with the same settings on a colleague's `MacOS` and there no such error occurred, although I am not sure what his MacOS version was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an antivirus running which was blocking the port. Turning off the firewall worked for me.